# NCrunch TestProjects with .net standard / core not working

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, ncrunch, .net-standard

I use ncrunch for my testing environment in vs2017.

In some projects i get a weired exception that projects could not be resolved

To reproduce i do the following steps:

- Create a new .net standard 1.4 project
- create a .net core xunit test project
- In the xunit project we add a reference to the .net standard project

Error:

Quote:

> NCrunch: If you are experiencing problems in getting this project to
>   build, have a look at
>   http://www.ncrunch.net/d...ng_project-build-issues 
>   ..............\vs2017\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets
>   (92, 5): Cannot find project info for
>   'C:\Users\BoasE\AppData\Local\NCrunch\50412\8\dev\BLS_UserApi\src\BoundContextes\Subscriptions\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj'.
>   This can indicate a missing project reference.

*Remarks:
As the descriped problem cost me some time and the exception is not obvious that it is related to a compatibility issue i post this save their time.*

Answer (score 0):

Currently .net standard / core is not supported. it is plmaned for begin of march 2017

> Please note that NCrunch does not yet support netstandard or .NET core
>   projects. This is currently a work in progress

https://ncrunch.uservoice.com/forums/245203-feature-requests/suggestions/8065623-support-net-core-net-standard-previously-known